# Ubuntu software can't show any app in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

After upgrading from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 ubuntu software can't show any apps.

Comment: did you update all packages and apps. If not use `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`

Comment: Yeah.but nothing happens.

Comment: I install ubuntu software with synaptic package manager and it worked.